# is there a way to get haptic feedback on keyboard?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, keyboard, touch

I've got a Lumia 535 and I'm used to haptic feedback on my Android phones, is there any way I can get it on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not available in all models, but:

*Go to -> **Settings** -> **Extras** -> **Touch** and toggle the switch "**Vibrate when I tap the navigation keys**".*

Comment: I think he means having haptic feedback when typing on the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Indrek I think you are right... in that case there are no news for that, it's still not possile and there is no App for that (at least that I know of..)